# Add two different sized tuples in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am new to erlang , and i am trying to figure out how to add two different sized tuples in erlang, for a exemple i want to add the following tuples

```
[{{"f"},2},{{"e","r"},3}]
```

to generate the following the following tuple

```
[{"f","e","r"},5}]
```

I tried to use insert_element/3 but no luck , here is my attempt:

```
[H1,H2|T]=[{{"f"},2},{{"e","r"},3}],
{Key1,Value1} = H1,
{Key2,Value2} = H2,
insert_element(1, {Key1,Value1+Value2},Key2).
```

which results in the following output:

```
{{"e","r"},{"f"},5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know in advance how long your tuples would be, the simplest way to concatenate them would be to convert them to lists with `tuple_to_list`, concatenate the lists, and then convert the result back to a tuple with `list_to_tuple`:

```
> Tuple1 = {"f"}.
{"f"}
> Tuple2 = {"e", "r"}.
{"e","r"}
> list_to_tuple(tuple_to_list(Tuple1) ++ tuple_to_list(Tuple2)).
{"f","e","r"}
```

Comment: Looks great, but i want to add the second elements of the tuples togther as well

Comment: It looks like you've already got that working in the code in your question.